Dynamic factor analysis/Kalman filter using fixed scores/state and dynamic loadings/observation model?
I have to following data setting. There's $n$ genomes whose expression for a trait of interest is measured in $p$ locations. This is repeated for $\tau$ years so the total number of datapoints is $n\times p \times \tau$. Assume that within a particular year we can use a factor analysis model to analyze the data such that for any genome $i$ in year $k$:
$$y_{ik}=\Lambda_k x_i + \epsilon_{ik}$$
with $\epsilon_{ik} \sim N(0, \Psi)$, $x_{i} \sim N(0, I)$, and thus $y_{ik} \sim N(0, \Lambda_k\Lambda^{\top}_k+\Psi)$.
In other words, I'd like the loadings to vary with time while the factor scores remain fixed. My reasoning for this is that the latent factors represent environmental types that can be used to describe any observed location as those locations are correlated to the latent environmental types through $\Lambda_k$. The loadings are time dependent because the environment at observed locations changes through time due to say climate change. Because not all locations change in the same way, the correlations between locations change over time.
I would like the factor scores to remain fixed, however. My reasoning for this is that the genomes do not change over time, and thus their expression in a hypothetical location that is perfectly correlated to one of the fixed environmental types does not change with time.
Is there any model that can accommodate this? I've looked into dynamic factor analysis and Kalman filters, as well as a number of stackexchange posts e.g., here but I haven't gotten much wiser. Many of the literature I've found either keeps the loadings fixed
